# converting MongoDB function foreach into mgo (Golang) function

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

This is function that tries to update the code matching  by its value

the `res collection`  as having the `code of Marque` it will be compared with `doc.Marque` if it is the case it will be replaced by the `value of the marque`.

This code is working perfectly in `mongoDB CLI`, but as i am working with `GO`.

I tried to convert it into `mgo` as you may see below but it is not working , i did not find the foreach function in `mgo` , is there something to be replaced with in this case ?  thanks for the help

```
db.res.find().forEach(function(doc){

var v = db.brands.findOne({code: doc.Marque});
if(v){ 
    db.res.update({"Marque": doc.Marque},
                  {$set: {"Marque":v.value}}, {multi: true});
     }
});
```

Here is what i tried :

```
result:=Results{}
pipe:=res.find(bson.M{}).Iter()

for pipe.Next(&result) {
brands:=brands.findOne({code: doc.Marque});

   if(v){ 

   pipe.update({"Marque": doc.Marque},
     {$set: {"Marque": v.value}}, {multi: true});

    }
                       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit the mgo [Godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo) may help you understand how it works.

Second, exported types/functions in Golang are begin with a capital letter. So `res.find`, `brands.findOne`, ... should be `res.Find`, `brands.FineOne` respectively, if such functions exist.

```
// let's say you have a type like this
type myResult struct {
    ID     bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    Marque string        `bson:"Marque"`
    // other fields...
}

// and another type like this
type myCode struct {
    Code string `bson:"code"`
    // other fields...
}

res := db.C("res")
brands := db.C("brands")
result := myResult{}

// iterate all documents
iter := res.Find(nil).Iter()    
for iter.Next(&result) {
    var v myCode
    err := brands.Find(bson.M{"code": result.Marque}).One(&v)
    if err != nil {
        // maybe not found or other reason,
        // it is recommend to have additional check
        continue
    }

    query := bson.M{"_id": result.ID}
    update := bson.M{"Marque": v.value}
    if err = res.Update(query, update); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
}

if err := iter.Close(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```